# ASP.NET How to set a property to every object of a specific type

Tags: asp.net, default-value

I was wondering if there is a way to set by default the value of an attribute for all specific asp:object

As an example: Set the text property for all asp:TextBox objects in the web application to "Please insert text"

This example is not what I am trying to achieve, just an example to clarify.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to accomplish what you need using [Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You could derive from the usercontrol and set the Text property in the constructor.

Comment: I could, but the application is already built and there are quite a few objects I needed to change... I was looking for a way to avoid this extra work.

Answer (score 1):

Derive a control, and then use the little known [tagMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164641.aspx) feature to replace it across the app.

```
 class MyTextBox : TextBox {
     public MyTextBox() : base() {
        this.Text = "Please insert text";
     }
 }

 <pages>
    <tagMapping>
       <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"
        mappedTagType="MyTextBox, MyWebControls.dll" />
    </tagMapping>
 </pages>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a TextBoxAdapter that changes the Text property before rendering the control.

Take a quick look at [Architectural Overview of Adaptive Control Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67276kc5.aspx) at MSDN. Read about Control Adapters, they can do what you want.